# When developing CapacitorJS or Ionic applications for iOS, how do I embed content in the final archive?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

Is there a way, when developing iOS apps via CapacitorJS or Ionic to embed specific content in the final built archive?

For context, the automated part of the review process is not detecting particular content, despite being in the app:

> We were able to locate the Terms of Use and Privacy Policy in the binary.